# quasar mode add cordova does nothing

Tags: cordova, quasar-framework

I'm developing using [Quasar framework](https://quasar.dev) and [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), so I followed an [instruction](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/preparation#2.-Add-Cordova-Quasar-Mode) and did `quasar mode add cordova` but noting happen. 
It used to work fine and create a `/src-cordova` folder, but it is a first time I'm trying to do this (add cordova to existing project) after the new v.1
the only output is like this:

```
MAC:stats-front pvkovalev$ quasar mode add cordova
 app:mode Detecting installed modes... +0ms

 Mode PWA........ no
 Mode SSR........ no
 Mode CORDOVA.... no
 Mode ELECTRON... no

MAC:stats-front pvkovalev$
```

and just in case here is my `quasar info`:

```
MAC:stats-front pvkovalev$ quasar info

Operating System            Darwin(18.7.0) - darwin/x64
NodeJs                      10.16.0

Global packages             
  NPM                       6.10.2
  yarn                      Not installed
  quasar-cli                0.17.26
  vue-cli                   3.9.3
  cordova                   9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

Important local packages    
  quasar-cli                Not installed
  quasar-framework          Not installed
  quasar-extras             Not installed
  vue                       2.6.10  (Reactive, component-oriented view layer for modern web interfaces.)
  vue-router                3.0.7   (Official router for Vue.js 2)
  vuex                      3.1.1   (state management for Vue.js)
  electron                  Not installed
  electron-packager         Not installed
  electron-builder          Not installed
  @babel/core               7.5.5   (Babel compiler core.)
  webpack                   4.35.3  (Packs CommonJs/AMD modules for the browser. Allows to split your codebase into multiple bundles, which can be loaded on demand. Support loaders to preprocess files, i.e. json, jsx, es7, css, less, ... and your custom stuff.)
  webpack-dev-server        3.7.2   (Serves a webpack app. Updates the browser on changes.)
  workbox-webpack-plugin    4.3.1   (A plugin for your Webpack build process, helping you generate a manifest of local files that workbox-sw should precache.)
  register-service-worker   1.6.2   (Script for registering service worker, with hooks)

MAC:stats-front pvkovalev$
```

Does anyone know how to fix that? Did I miss anything?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an issue and a solution.

- Issue:

Quasar v.1 version of CLI is using `@quasar/cli` and v.0.17x is using `quasar-cli`. It's confusing like hell and took me sometime to realize it

- Solution:

Delete the old package using `npm uninstall -g quasar-cli` and add a new `npm i -g @quasar/cli`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create a Quasar app using:

```
quasar create app-name
```

And then you can add Cordova to your Quasar app

```
quasar mode add cordova
```

Now your Qusar app is ready to go with Cordova.